# Pentaho commandline nullpointer exception

Tags: pentaho, pdi

Pentaho PDI version 8.3.0 CE if it matters

When I try to run a job or transformation commandline using kitchen or pan respectively I get a nullpointer exception. This happens only when trying to run something from a repository. 
When I try to run the same transformation or job from spoon, all is fine and the job runs great.

I use the following commands, which both provide the same error:

> ./pan.sh -trans=get_clusters -rep=myrepo -user=admin -pass=mypass -dir=/Transformations

and

> ./kitchen.sh -job=scheduled_update_job -rep=myrepo -user=admin -pass=mypass -dir=/Jobs

NOTE: This error also happens when I try to run the job or transformation from a docker container.

The error I receive is as follows and identical for PAN and Kitchen:

```
020/02/05 09:07:56 - Pan - Start of run.
Processing has stopped because of an error: null
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.pentaho.di.core.plugins.PluginRegistry.getPluginId(PluginRegistry.java:689)
    at org.pentaho.di.core.plugins.PluginRegistry.getPlugin(PluginRegistry.java:715)
    at org.pentaho.di.core.plugins.PluginRegistry.loadClass(PluginRegistry.java:370)
    at org.pentaho.di.base.AbstractBaseCommandExecutor.establishRepositoryConnection(AbstractBaseCommandExecutor.java:195)
    at org.pentaho.di.pan.PanCommandExecutor.execute(PanCommandExecutor.java:119)
    at org.pentaho.di.pan.Pan.main(Pan.java:270)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.pentaho.commons.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:92)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: FYI: I also set the KETTLE_HOME as mentioned in the documentation. This made no difference in either the local setup nor my docker container.

Comment: Also: I have tossed away the karaf caches for both pan and kitchen entirely, but this does not solve it either.

Comment: It looks like it can't get some plugin, perhaps the repository plugin. Are you running it from the same data-integration folder? If not you might be missing a plugin.

Comment: Also, if you configured the KETTLE_HOME differently from the one used by Spoon, check if there's a valid repositories.xml

Comment: Thanks for your comments Cyrus. I am running this in the same directory as the spoon is located. I thought the same thing but to me it makes no sense that spoon is able to work just fine, but the pan/kitchen tools don't. I did notice that when I export the files and run them commandline, I DO get some results. This leads me to believe that for some reason kitchen/pan are not able to connect to the repo whilst spoon can.
Also, they use the same KETTLE_HOME files and I made sure it existed. I could confirm by deleting the karaf caches for both and watch them rebuild.

Comment: Try running it from your home directory instead, using the full path for kitchen.sh/pan.sh. That is how I always run kitchen jobs, from cron or manually.

Comment: Hmmmm. For some reason this worked! Now only to figure out why it works like this (I would expect this to be the reason for setting KETTLE_HOME in the first place) and then figure out how to incorporate into a docker container. Thanks Cyrus and please turn the comment into an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run the job from your home directory (as working directory) using the full path of pan.sh or kitchen.sh.

I'm not sure what exactly causes the trouble. Likely causes:

- Your KETTLE_HOME is not valid, causing Pentaho to look for .kettle in the working directory. (Do not include .kettle in the HOME)
- A variant of this is that you don't have permissions on the files if you copied/moved them as root.
- Your user does not have write access to the data-integration directory, causing some failure writing a configuration that would normally go into the working dir. *It is normal to run Pentaho with an account that does not have write access here, that is not the problem, just that it doesn't like a non-writable working dir.*