# kitchen pentaho thrown error when call by bat

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

I can't solve this problema when I call Kitchen by bat file (i have a job calling a transformation)
Any ideia?

```
PS D:\Proj\ETL> .\jobResp.bat                                                                               
D:\Proj\ETL>D:\Program\pdi-ce-8.3.0.0-371\data-integration\kitchen.bat /rep:ETL SQL Server /job:jobResp /level:Basic   1>"D:\logETLs\jobResp.log"
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0
mar 08, 2020 1:20:31 PM org.apache.karaf.main.Main$KarafLockCallback lockAquired
INFORMAÃıES: Lock acquired. Setting startlevel to 100
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.pentaho.di.core.plugins.PluginRegistry.getPluginId(PluginRegistry.java:689)
        at org.pentaho.di.core.plugins.PluginRegistry.getPlugin(PluginRegistry.java:715)
        at org.pentaho.di.core.plugins.PluginRegistry.loadClass(PluginRegistry.java:370)
        at org.pentaho.di.base.AbstractBaseCommandExecutor.establishRepositoryConnection(AbstractBaseCommandExecutor.java:195)
        at org.pentaho.di.kitchen.KitchenCommandExecutor.execute(KitchenCommandExecutor.java:115)
        at org.pentaho.di.kitchen.Kitchen.main(Kitchen.java:286)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.pentaho.commons.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:92)
PS D:\Projetos\ETL>
```

Comment: I m using a repository

Comment: Without a [mcve] it seems unlikely we can help, but did you see [Pentaho commandline nullpointer exception](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60071540/3744182)?  Could this be a duplicate of that question?

Comment: Difficult to understand the problem, go to the path where your kitchen.bat file exist and then try to run the job which you want to execute by following https://help.pentaho.com/Documentation/7.0/0L0/0Y0/070 document.

Answer (score 0):

There is a missing file or bad path provided.

> java.lang.NullPointerException

> D:\Proj\ETL>D:\Program\pdi-ce-8.3.0.0-371\data-integration\kitchen.bat
> /rep:ETL SQL Server /job:jobResp /level:Basic

> "D:\logETLs\jobResp.log"